# Using I/O to compare files, keep getting runtime error

Tags: c++, input, io, compare

I have an assignment that asks

```
a.) Prompts the user to input the names of 3 files: two input files
and an output file.  
b.) Reads in the two input files line by line and compares the two
lines.
c.) For each line in the inputs, the output should have the line
number, a colon (':'), and either "OK" if the lines match or "DIFF" if
the lines are different.
The input files may be of different lengths. 
- Your program should be case-sensitive, so you do NOT need to worry about converting 

text to lowercase or uppercase.

For example:

input1:
abc
def
g h i

input2:
abc
DEf
ghi
uub

output:
1:OK
2:DIFF
3:DIFF
4:DIFF
```

Basically I have the code written but every time I try to run this on Putty I get, it compiles correctly though.

```
:: a.out
Please enter input file name: abc
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Can't open input file: abc
Abort (core dumped)
```

So before I even input my file name, it get the return error, I wrote each section of my input and output according to Stroustrup's book. What exactly am I missing, or am I just doing this wrong? 
Thank you.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities_3.h"

int main()
{
    //Input 1
    cout  << "Please enter input file name: ";
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    ifstream ist1(name.c_str());
    if (!ist1) error("Can't open input file: ",name);

    //Input 2
    cout << "Please enter another input file name: ";
    string name2;
    cin >> name2;
    ifstream ist2(name2.c_str());
    if (!ist2) error("Can't open input file name: ",name2);

    //Output
    cout << "Please enter name of output file: ";
    string oname;
    cin >> oname;
    ofstream ost(oname.c_str());
    if (!ost) error("Can't open output file: ",oname);

    string s, t;
    int i = 1;
    int flag = 1;
    while(true) 
    {
        if (!getline(ist1, s)) {flag = 1; break;}
        if (!getline(ist2, t)) {flag = 2; break;}
        ost << i;
        if (s == t)
            ost << ": OK\n";
        else
            ost << ": DIFF\n";
        i++;
    }

    if (flag == 2) {
        ost << i << ": DIFF\n"; 
        i++;
        while (getline(ist1, s)) {ost << i << ": DIFF\n"; i++;}
    }

    if (flag == 1) {
        while (getline(ist2, t)) {ost << i << ": DIFF\n"; i++;}
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes, but I'm not exactly sure what extension its supposed to be..? if that makes any sense. I have abc.txt but it doesn't do anything. I see other files under the same root folder named "core" (file) and "a.out" (OUT file), should I edit those accordingly?

Comment: There's your problem, then; you were telling your program the input file was `abc`, but it's `abc.txt`.

Comment: lol dang, well I tried inputting "abc.txt" and I still got the same runtime error. I then proceeded to make a copy of "Core" and renamed it "abc", along with three other files so my input 1 is abc, input 2 is yes, and output is hola. Now putty is actually doing something, I'm sure it got stuck on the while loop.

Comment: You probably don't want to use `core` as an input file unless you know what you're doing; `core` is a binary debugging dump, and will almost certainly not line up with any of your other text files.

Comment: ahh okay gotcha. Core actually popped out on my root folder itself. no wonder its taking Putty forever since its 3mb. Since I kept on getting the same runtime error for abc.txt, which type of file extension should I be using?

Comment: `txt` should be fine, but you need to make sure you type that into your program.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is fine, but you need to make sure you type in the whole filename including the file extension. I was able to successfully run your program with these files:

- `program.cc` — your program's source
- `program` — your program, compiled
- `file-a.txt` — a text file:

  ```
  Hello, world!
  This is a file.
  This line is different.
  But same again.
  ```
- `file-b.txt` — another text file:

  ```
  Hello, world!
  This is a file.
  This line differs from file A.
  But same again.
  ```

I was then able to successfully run your program:

```
$ ./program
Please enter input file name: file-a.txt
Please enter another input file name: file-b.txt
Please enter name of output file: diffed.txt
```

It successfully created `diffed.txt` with this output:

```
1: OK
2: OK
3: DIFF
4: OK
```

Comment: yes!! it worked :D

My problem was that my abc.txt file was actually.... abc.txt.txt can't believe that was my issue. I used your example and it indeed created diffed.txt ---- however it's taking its sweet sweet time, is this supposed to happen? I still haven't gotten the 1. OK, 2, OK, 3. DIFF, and 4.OK.

Comment: ^In response, I ctrl+z it became a 615mb file. (What the heck happened).

Comment: @enigmuz: No, it ran very quickly for me. I hope you still aren't using that core file as one of the inputs; that could cause a problem like that.

Comment: Very odd, I created two txt (file-a,file-b) files with what you provided, and ran my code. It indeed did create diffed.txt however Putty still kept on running and making the diffed.txt file larger and larger. I made sure to erase everything on my root folder and only have my program and both txt files there. Perhaps its my compiler or putty that is causing this? Not exactly sure. Good thing is, at least the code works.

Comment: Figured out my problem, it was just some dumb technical thing, everything is working as it should now :D thank you icktoofay! :D